# Can I trust local variable value when analyzing a dump with Windbg?

Tags: c++, debugging, windbg

I see strange things like a pointer values changing the values (0 or something valid) between 2 calls with no change. Same with a enum values. The values are simply forwarded, no chances to be modified. The dump is minidunp.

Comment: On line 3, your cast is invalid and causes undefined behavior. Also, don't say `++i + ++i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dv /V to reveal if a local variable is living in a register.
Like here:

0:000> dv /v
**@ecx**            this = 0x0018fe10

To get rid of this, you must remove optimization when compiling.

Comment: thanks. this is what I need. I way to determine if a var is valid.

Answer (score 3):

Optimized build I assume? The problem is that the CPU doesn't deal in variables, but works with memory addresses and registers. As it happens, in release builds one register may be shared by many variables - not all at the same time, of course. But if the debugger can't work out what variable is *now* in the register, it may get quite confused.

Comment: that explains the change of values, the registry are reused. Is there a way to overcome this ?

Comment: 0:001> ?? this; -> class myClass * 0xff7e5c8e; !address 0xff7e5c8e -> address ff7e5c8e not found in any VAD ----. This is the result of memory corruption or optimization ? The this ptr value should be valid and I have heap info in the dump