# Parameter oddity in Windows crash dumps

Tags: parameters, windbg, crash-dumps

In Windows crash dumps, especially the ones we get from Windows Error Reporting, we often see parameter values that vary across calls when they shouldn't. For example:

```
void foo(int id)
{
    ...
{

void bar(int id)
{
    foo(id);
    ...
}
```

According to WinDbg, the values of 'id' are inexplicably different in foo() and bar(). We see this **a lot**, and there's nothing in our code that can account for it (IOW, we aren't doing anything with the value of 'id' before the call to foo).

Does anyone have an explanation for this?

Comment: the variable just gets optimized, dependent on where you are on the calling stack the stack point where you thought your variable would be is reused for something else - studying the code the compiler generates will generally provide necessary information to find out the value. you just have to keep in mind that it's not always possible. why is your program crashing?

Comment: Take a look at :  
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877383/can-i-trust-local-variable-value-when-analyzing-a-dump-with-windbg>  
Isn’t this the same problem?

Comment: deemok: Yes, I guess it's probably optimization. Sometimes if we go far enough back in the call stack we can see the correct value. Why is the progam crashing? We're not sure. That's why we look at the crash dumps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Stack corruption?  The values you are seeing are really values on the stack and when foo was called, a copy was made just for foo by pushing the value id had at that time.  So if foo changes its local copy it would obviously have a different value, but if someone overruns an array (I'm guessing this is in C) it could also overwrite the id value.

So for example, suppose that abc called foo and had an array of length 120 declared locally.  Someone has a pointer to that array and copies 240 bytes into it without noticing that this overruns the end of the array.  Well, those extra 120 bytes would land on top of the variables foo is using as locals.

Comment: Well, that was the first thing we thought of, but this is happening too often and in too many different executables for it to be a reasonable explanation. The example above is typical of what we're seeing. A function gets a simple parameter and _immediately_ calls a second function, but the param values are different in the two functions (or at least windbg shows them as different--we're not convinced that they really were). Hard to see how the stack could get corrupted in that situation.